# ERC20 ICO - Transfer tokens

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, ico

To make an initial ICO do I need to transfer TOKENS to the ICO smart contract? Or can I use a wallet that has the tokens and then transfer from that wallet to the buyer's wallet?

Answer (score 0):

Either way is possible.
If the tokens are in a contract, use directly `transfer`.
If the tokens are in the owner/admin wallet, then use `transferFrom` and approve contract to spend from owner/admin wallet.

Comment: Thanks for answers.. How use fn transfer?